# Pressing keyboard up and down for mat-form-field-infix field Selenium

Tags: java, angular, selenium, automation

I was wondering how could I simulate keyboard up and down buttons for a drop-down list when dealing with mat-form-field-infix? I tried using Robot framework but it won't display the drop down-list unless i simulate it manually.

```
robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Comment: I tried the following methods and still facing the same issues.